# " is being a big flaw " or " is a big flaw"?

Tags: difference, grammaticality-in-context

Could some one please explain?

What is the difference between following sentence constructions?

> 1. Interior water leaking is being a big flaw.

and

> 2. Interior water leaking is a big flaw.

what is the grammar used here?

Comment: Regarding the difference between present simple and present continuous: the simple one conveys a factual statement and the continuous (progressive) one conveys a momentary event related to the time frame within which the statement lies time-wise. Also, "water leaking" in that sentence does not sound right. Perhaps, "the water leaking into the interior space" is what you are intended to say. For a more concise sentence, native English speakers can help. I don't have any suggestion in mind right now. :-)

Comment: "One big flaw is interior water leaks." would be an alternative that sounds better to my ear. The usage "is being" after another -ing word (leaking) is exceedingly rare. I don't recall hearing it ever, or at least in many years. Although your example 1 is meaningful in some sort of textbook way, it simply would not be used. Number 2 would.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "is being" implies a temporary state that will probably stop at some point.

If you say "Interior water leaking is being a big flaw", you're implying that it's a flaw now, but it will probably stop being a flaw in the future. That sounds kind of strange.

If you say "Interior water leaking is a big flaw", you're just saying that it's a flaw now; you're not saying anything about whether or not it will stop in the future.

Comment: To add, you would never say "Interior water leaking is being a big flaw." Instead, to make it temporary, you would say something like "Interior water leaking is currently a big flaw." "Being" is usually restricted to phrases that involve *actively* presenting yourself a certain way, like "being nice" or "being a bad boy." When applied to an inanimate object, it has a personifying effect.